# Alternatives for "I told you so."

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Sometimes, "I told you so" is expected by the target. What if we want to surprise them with another famous phrase which would deliver the same message, perhaps with more intensity. Sometimes, "I told you so" doesn't quite say it, maybe because we wish it carried more weight.

What are other possibilities? A single word, or phrase or idiom maybe.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1yKxL6Ch6E

Comment: Or you could just say, "See?"

Comment: @RegDwigнt I would've appreciated a heads up (text description) on what your link is. I followed it long enough to see the title and then backed out because I was on mobile, now I see (on desktop) it's exactly what I was checking that it wasn't. :/ It's very annoying to always give an answer that someone has mentioned before me in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other possibilities:

> Don't say I didn't warn you!
>
> *Now* do you believe me!?
>
> What did I tell you!?
>
> You just had to do it anyway, didn't you?
>
> You should have listened to me...
>
> How many times did I tell you *not* to do that?
>
> You're a bit of a slow learner, aren't you?
>
> You just won't be told, will you?

Answer (score 2):

In the words of the great and fictitious nutcase, Sheldon Cooper, from [The Big Bang Theory episode entitled 'The 21 Second Excitation'](http://the-big-bang-theory.com/quotes/episode/408/):

> "Under normal circumstances I'd say I told you so. But, as I have told you so with such vehemence and frequency already the phrase has lost all meaning. Therefore, I will be replacing it with the phrase, *I have informed you thusly*."

[See Youtube clip here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHBB3WWhxr4)

Answer (score 1):

I have used «voilà» (or «voila») in comparable situations. It may be loosely translated as «there you go» and thus seems right for the occasion. It has the advantage of being very concise and the disadvantage of being rather French, and it may not necessarily carry more weight if it is not understood. However, it does imply that you knew that a particular event would occur and, possibly, that you had warned the addressee.

Answer (score 0):

To convey a stronger meaning the following come to mind:

- *It serves you right!!*
- [You have made the bed](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/You%27ve+made+your+bed)    ( now lie in it)!!
- That will teach you!!

Comment: -1 Sorry, but none of these convey the idea that the person had been forewarned by you.

Answer (score 0):

I think "what did I say?" conveys that meaning.

Comment: +1 Don't know why you got a down vote for that, it's a phrase I use a lot. You can shout this loudly, you can't shout _I told you so_ as easily.

Answer (score 0):

Duh! would be a single word answer.

**duh** |də, do͝o| exclam. informal
used to comment on an action perceived as foolish or stupid, or a statement perceived as obvious: I left the keys in the ignition—duh! | Leopold correctly informs him that the opera is in Italian (duh!).

Answer (score 0):

A new phrase which I have been hearing lately:

"Can someone please answer that phone, because I called it."